# Optimizing linq efficiency

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I got this linq:

```
return ngrms.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(s => new { Text = s.Key, Count = s.Count() })    
            .Where(x => x.Count > minCount)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Text, g => g.Count);
```

ngrms is `IEnumerable<String>`

Is there a way that I can optimize this code? 
I don't care if I have to rewrite all the code and open to all low level tweaks.

Comment: Well, what about you do some homework. Assuming ngrms is an entity framework query.... look at the generated SQL. Simple like that. That said, given that a Dictionary is not ordered, what is the sense of the ToOrder? Except making it slower (because the order is gone the moment the dictionary is filled).

Comment: @TomTom No ngrams is a IEnumerable<String>

Comment: Which is what below? What is the underlying storage?

Comment: Other than moving `Where` before `OrderByDescending` (or remove `OrderByDescending` at all), I don't see what else you can do with LINQ to Objects. What is the actual problem - execution time, memory usage etc.?

Comment: You don't need the `OrderByDescending` if you're creating a dictionary.

Comment: are you sure the groupby condition is correct? `ngrms.GroupBy(x => x)`, you are grouping the object so the count for each group will be 1 always.

Comment: @Vinit Not really - OP already clarified that `x` is a `string`

Comment: @Vinit In this case, if your sequence is `{ "a", "a", "b" }` you will get two groups, one with 2 elements and one with only one.

Comment: @Vinit it is a list with a duplicate strings and groupby does a count of duplicates

Comment: @all - Oh, i overlooked `IEnumerable<string>`. thanks

Comment: in c#7 use tuples instead of anonymous type. it can be slightly faster.  simply `.Select(s => (Text = s.Key, Count = s.Count()) )`

Comment: @realPro At the end, is `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)` needed or not?

Comment: What is the min count?

Comment: As written the order-by is useless. The reason to do an order-by here would be to stop looking at groups that don't meet the "where" criterion early, but you're not doing that either; you've used `Where` but I think `TakeWhile` was intended. But there's a larger problem; this technique presupposes that doing the superlinear sort is worthwhile to save time on the linear filter; that doesn't really make any sense unless comparing strings is *cheaper* than comparing *integers* -- but it very much is not!

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the interesting reply. I suspect that you(and few others) did not understand what I am tying to do. The goal is to create a frequent word list which is sorted by frequency so that later I can do .Take(3) from the dictionary and this will result in top 3 most frequent words. Of course the top 3 is not enough, I need the rest of the data as well.

Comment: That is not what `ToDictionary` does. You need a sorted dictionary. Also, you have learned that **explaining what you are doing in the question tells the people answering it what you are doing** so that they have context.

Comment: @EricLippert The OP is 100% self explanatory: group-by + count, what can be explained here? I sort by value, so sorted dictionary is not an option and even if I re-engineer all the code the performance improvement  will be non-significant.

Answer (score 3):

If you implement a `Dictionary` that can be incremented (emulating a multiset or bag) then you can speed up about 3x faster than LINQ, but the difference is small unless you have a lot of `ngrms`. On a list of 10 million, with about 100 unique values, the LINQ code still takes less than a second on my PC. If your LINQ code takes time 1, a `foreach` with a `Dictionary<string,int>` takes 0.85 and this code takes 0.32.

Here is the class for creating an updateable value in the `Dictionary`:

```
public class Ref<T> {
    public T val { get; set; }
    public Ref(T firstVal) => val = firstVal;
    public static implicit operator T(Ref<T> rt) => rt.val;
}
```

(If C# allowed `operator ref T` you could return a `ref` to the `val` property and almost treat a `Ref<T>` as if it were a lvalue of type `T`.)

Now you can count the occurrences of the strings in a `Dictionary<string,Ref<int>>` with only one lookup per string:

```
var dictCounts = new Dictionary<string, Ref<int>>();
foreach (var s in ngrms) {
    if (dictCounts.TryGetValue(s, out var refn))
        ++refn.val;
    else
        dictCounts.Add(s, new Ref<int>(1));
}
```

Finally you can compute the answer by filtering the counts to the ones you want to keep:

```
var ans = dictCounts.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > minCount).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.val);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Unfortunately the performance improvement I get from your code is around one percent(1%). I will keep my code.

Comment: How large is `ngrms`?

Comment: Before group 1-2k after 100-200

Answer (score 1):

Going by your linq query, you may consider rewriting the code using simple `foreach` loop for better performance, like below. It takes `o(n)` time complexity to execute:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var s in ngrms)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(s))
        dict[s]++;
    else
        dict.Add(s, 1);
}
return dict.Where(a => a.Value > minCount);
```

Comment: The last `.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`